# Is there any API Document Browser like Dash on Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, document-management

I've seen my friend enjoy using Dash, in which you could look up all kinds of language document, Java, c#, Android, Javascript, JQuery, etc. That makes life much much more easier!! Does Anyone knows if there's alternative on Ubuntu? I search desperately but no

[Dash: Code snippet manager and Cocoa documentation browser.](https://kapeli.com/dash)

Answer (score 55):

You might want to check out [Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/). I just started implementing it this weekend. It's intended to be a documentation browser like Dash, working on Linux.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Zeal Screenshot]

Comment: Didn't know Zeal. Looks promising, very dash-like, although it lacks the snippets functionallity.

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps [devdocs.io](http://devdocs.io/) would be an option. It is also available as app extension for [google chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devdocs/mnfehgbmkapmjnhcnbodoamcioleeooe?hl=en).

[image]

Comment: You could at least provide a link ;)

Comment: like it! but my chrome just get fatter & fatter. LOL

Comment: It's really cool, has even an offline feature.

Answer (score 4):

[devhelp [image: Install devhelp]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/devhelp) may help you

> Devhelp is an API documentation browser for GTK+ and GNOME. It works
>   natively with gtk-doc (the API reference framework developed for GTK+
>   and used throughout GNOME for API documentation). If you use gtk-doc
>   with your project, you can use Devhelp to browse the documentation.

[website](https://live.gnome.org/devhelp)

**screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For JQuery there is [JQAPI](http://jqapi.com/). You can even install it as package!

```
$ sudo apt-get install jquery-alternative-doc
```

Then browse to this file in your browser.

```
file:///usr/share/doc/jquery-alternative-doc/index.html
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP. Dash is a native desktop client that provides useful search features, and it downloads docsets or uses local docsets.

Answer (score 0):

If you use emacs then give [helm-dash](https://github.com/areina/helm-dash) a try.